Spring data - Object's data not filled after saving it
I have a simple spring application where I have an ArticleDAO and SupplierDAO. I'm having some problems at retrieving the name of SupplierDAO right after saving ArticleDAO which has a @ManyToOne relationship (many articles can point to the same supplier). When I save it I just have its ID but when I try to retrieve it just after saving it I am not getting its name but if I try to retrieve it afterwards then I get all its info. The SupplierDAO does exist in database and has a name already. Why is this happening?
ArticleDAO and SupplierDAO:
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Table(name = "article")
public class ArticleDAO {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "selling_price")
    private BigDecimal sellingPrice;

    @Column(name = "supplier_price")
    private BigDecimal supplierPrice;

    @Column(name = "user")
    private String user;

    @Column(name = "selling_unit_type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ArticleSellingUnitType sellingUnitType;

    @Column(name = "inventory_amount")
    private Integer inventoryAmount;

    @Column(name = "picture")
    private String picture;

    @Column(name = "color")
    private String color;

    @Column(name = "reference")
    private String reference;

    @Column(name = "bar_code")
    private String barCode;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private SupplierDAO supplier;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @Table(name = "supplier")
    public static class SupplierDAO {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Integer id;

        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;
    }

}

Service method to save and get all info from SupplierDAO:
public class ArticlesServiceImpl implements ArticlesService {
    private final ArticleRepository articleRepository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Override
    public List<Article> createArticles(final List<Article> articles) {
        List<ArticleDAO> articleDAOS this.modelMapper.map(articles, new TypeToken<List<ArticleDAO>>(){}.getType());
        this.articleRepository.saveAll(articleDAOS);
        articleDAOS = this.articleRepository.findAll();
        return this.modelMapper.map(articleDAOS, new TypeToken<List<Article>>(){}.getType());
    }
}

Article's Repository:
@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository extends JpaRepository<ArticleDAO, Integer> {
}

The suppliers I have in my database:

The call I make to create the article:
[
        {
            "name": "Botellín Mahou Clasica 23334333",
            "sellingPrice": 1.50,
            "supplierPrice": 0.44,
            "sellingUnitType": "WEIGHT",
            "inventoryAmount": 100,
            "picture": "picture.png",
            "color": "blue",
            "barCode": "123123123123",
            "reference": "800",
            "supplier": {
                "id": 6
            }
        }
    ]

The response I get (the error where supplier's name is missing) right after creating the article:
[
        {
            "name": "Botellín Mahou Clasica 23334333",
            "sellingPrice": 1.50,
            "supplierPrice": 0.44,
            "sellingUnitType": "WEIGHT",
            "inventoryAmount": 100,
            "picture": "picture.png",
            "color": "blue",
            "barCode": "123123123123",
            "reference": "800",
            "supplier": {
                "id": 6,
                "name": null
            }
        }
    ]

The response I get if I retrieve all the articles through another method after the article has already been created:
[
        {
            "name": "Botellín Mahou Clasica 23334333",
            "sellingPrice": 1.50,
            "supplierPrice": 0.44,
            "sellingUnitType": "WEIGHT",
            "inventoryAmount": 100,
            "picture": "picture.png",
            "color": "blue",
            "barCode": "123123123123",
            "reference": "800",
            "supplier": {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "VFGBO"
            }
        }
    ]

Why am I not getting the supplier's name on the first call when I'm creating the article? I am using MySql incase it's realed somehow.
Thanks!

Most likely it's the problem with mapping (and ModelMapper particularly). Can you add Article definition?

I don't think it's  the mapper fault bec as I commented I'm debugging it and the name is not present there.

Can you add Article definition?
